# Sendgrid and PHP 5.2.6

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have an older version of PHP (5.2.6). SendGrid SMTP APIs require at least PHP 5.3

What other options do I have to mass sending emails (~1k) using SendGrid service?

Is the WebAPI sufficient for my case?

Thank you.

Comment: seriously - upgrade your PHP! They stopped support for v5.2 nearly two years ago.

Comment: also, even if you can't update to 5.3 or 5.4, you should at least update your 5.2 to the last version (5.2.17). There's absolutely no excuse for running a version as old as 5.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP 5.3 limitation doesn't really have anything to do with SendGrid's API, it's just our official library only supports 5.3 and above.  You could easily swap it out for any generic SMTP library.

For example, [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) supports PHP 5.2 and up.

And yes, the web API will be sufficient for your use case.  It's identical to the SMTP API, except that it's over HTTP.